# The main application of my website is not viewed when running it

Tags: django, python-3.x, cpanel

[image]I am not able to launch my website. It is showing the bellow error when running it iPlanetHoster.

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /home/massvnrc/myproject/myproject/myapp/templates/index.html
No module named '/myapp'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    ***/home/massvnrc/myproject/myproject/myapp/templates/index.html
Django Version: 1.9.13
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
No module named '/myapp'
Exception Location: /home/massvnrc/virtualenv/myproject/3.7/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py in import_module, line 127
Python Executable:  /home/massvnrc/virtualenv/myproject/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/massvnrc/myproject',
 '/opt/passenger-5.3.7-9.el7.cloudlinux/src/helper-scripts',
 '/home/massvnrc/virtualenv/myproject/3.7/lib64/python37.zip',
 '/home/massvnrc/virtualenv/myproject/3.7/lib64/python3.7',
 '/home/massvnrc/virtualenv/myproject/3.7/lib64/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7',
 '/opt/alt/python37/lib/python3.7',
 '/home/massvnrc/virtualenv/myproject/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 23 Jan 2020 18:03:11 +0000
```

Here are some pictures that are showing where my files are located.

enter image description here

Can somebody tell me why I am getting this erro

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you registered your app in project settings file?

Comment: I think so. But if there is another way to register an app online especially in PlanetHoster or Cpanel, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You deployed the website with debug mode turned on - never do this, at least without restricting access.
Anyway, because of this I was able to see your `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include
# from .import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('', include('/myapp.urls')), ...
]
```

And installed apps from settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS  
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
```

I do not see myapp registered in settings. You need to add it.
Next is that `include('/myapp.urls')` should be changes to `include('myapp.urls')`